# How do I connect an existing workflow to a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have created a workflow which I found it in my list of workflows in SharePoint designer.

But when I check my list I can't find it.

So how can i add my workflow to my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you save your workflow you will also need to publish it to the list or site, you will see the publish button next to the save button in edit mode of the workflow.

If you have done that then do you know what type of workflow that's been created?  SharePoint Designer 2010 can create the following three types of workflow:

**List workflow**

This is associated to an existing list on your SharePoint site

**Reusable workflow**

This is associated to a content type used within your site

**Site workflow**

This workflow has n associated list or content type and can be started from the view all content page.

If you open SharePoint Designer and goto the workflow section, find your workflow and right click on it and select "Workflow Settings".  This page will tel you if it's associated to a list or content type.

Comment: thanks Stephen , it was a site workflow and all I need it's to redeploy it